# How can we collaborate over div's with contenteditable property enabled in ShareJs?

Tags: javascript, html, sharejs

I am using textarea property in sharejs to edit documents .
I wanted to know how can I collaborate div's with contenteditable property enabled ,so that I can implement rich text editors in my app using sharejs.

Comment: https://github.com/ottypes/rich-text#rich-text--